# HQL specify an order by property order?

Tags: hibernate, hql

How can I order by a specific property order in HQL?

For MySQL I can use: `SELECT * FROM question q ORDER BY q.status IN ("DONE", "NO_ACTION"), q.status IN ("NEW","SAVED"), q.created DESC`

but HQL doesn't allow `in` in `order by`.

Am I missing something? Is there some other way around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that MySQL syntax using ORDER BY xxx IN (XXX,XXX...) is not  SQL-ANSI supported function, it's a specific MySQL function.

So you should figure out another way to do what you want, by not using this function.

You can find [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) all the function supported by HQL.

Comment: thanks Rasatavohary but I appreciate that this SQL is MySQL specific. I was hoping that some one could help with producing some HQL that would produce the same result. I have read the HQL manual and haven't seen something that is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Not to revive a dead question, but

```
SELECT * FROM question q ORDER BY q.status IN ("DONE", "NO_ACTION"), q.status HAVING q.status IN ("NEW", "SAVED")
```

[Find "having clause"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping)